# What is the best way to repeat the elements in a vector in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust

I found this way, but it seems too verbose for such a common action:

```
fn double_vec(vec: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut vec1 = vec.clone();
    let vec2 = vec.clone();

    vec1.extend(vec2);

    vec1
}
```

I know that in JavaScript it could be just `arr2 = [...arr1, ...arr1]`.

Comment: Even in this solution, only one of those `.clone()`s is necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the concat method for this, it's simple:

```
fn double_vec(v: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    [&v[..], &v[..]].concat()
}
```

Unfortunately we have to make the vectors slices explicitly (here `&v[..]`); but otherwise this method is good because it allocates the result to the needed size directly and then does the copies.

Answer (score 13):

"Doubling a vector" isn't something that's really done very often so there's no shortcut for it. In addition, it matters what is inside the `Vec` because that changes what operations can be performed on it. In this specific example, the following code works:

```
let x = vec![1, 2, 3];

let y: Vec<_> = x.iter().cycle().take(x.len() * 2).collect();

println!("{:?}", y); //[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

The `cycle()` method requires that the items in the `Iterator` implement the `Clone` trait so that the items can be duplicated. So if the items in your `Vec` implement `Clone`, then this will work. Since immutable references (`&`) implement `Clone`, a `Vec<&Something>` will work but mutable references (`&mut`) do not implement `Clone` and thus a `Vec<&mut Something>` will not work.

Note that even if a type does not implement `Clone`, you can still clone references to that type:

```
struct Test;

fn test_if_clone<T: Clone>(_x: T) {}

fn main() {
    let x = Test;

    test_if_clone(x); //error[E0277]: the trait bound `Test: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied

    let y = &x;

    test_if_clone(y); //ok
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Building on Wesley's answer, you can also use [chain](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain) to glue two iterables together, one after the other. In the below example I use the same `Vec`'s `iter()` method twice:

```
let x = vec![1, 2, 3];

let y: Vec<_> = x.iter().chain(x.iter()).collect();

println!("{:?}", y); //[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: One thing that's probably worth mentioning is that the type of `y` is `Vec<&{integer}>` not `Vec<{integer>`. This is a good solution though since it allows you to handle vectors whose contents can't be cloned.

Answer (score 6):

The iterator methods are a likely to be a lot less efficient than a straight `memcpy` that vector extension is.

You own code does a `clone` too many; you can just reuse the by-value input:

```
fn double_vec(mut vec: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let clone = vec.clone();
    vec.extend(clone);
    vec
}
```

However, the nature of a `Vec` means this is likely to require a copy even if you managed to remove that clone, so you're not generally gaining much over just using `concat`.

Using `concat` on slices is fairly efficient, as it will preallocate the `Vec` in advance and then perform an efficient `extend_from_slice`. However, this does mean it's no longer particularly sensible to take a `Vec` as input; writing the following is strictly more flexible.

```
fn double_slice(slice: &[i32]) -> Vec<i32> {
    [slice, slice].concat()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Rust 1.53, [`Vec::extend_from_within`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend_from_within) makes it possible to more efficiently double a vector:

```rust
fn double_vec(vec: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    vec.extend_from_within(..);
}
```

Comment: `vec.repeat(1)` would also work. `extend_from_within()` provides flexibility which parts to copy, `repeat()` about the number of times the part is copied.